# Karma-jasmine not installing

Tags: node.js, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to `Unit Testing` so I only got to know `Jasmine` and `Karma` today.

I installed Karma:

```
npm init
npm install karma --save-dev
npm install -g karma-cli
npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
karma init
```

However when I try to launch karma start `karma.conf.js` it throws me an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.require.resolve (module.js:389:19)
    at initJasmine (/Users/appfoundry/Projects/Unit Testing/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/index.js:8:42)
    at Array.invoke (/Users/appfoundry/Projects/Unit Testing/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at get (/Users/appfoundry/Projects/Unit Testing/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
    at /Users/appfoundry/Projects/Unit Testing/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:137:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Server._start (/Users/appfoundry/Projects/Unit Testing/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:136:21)
    at invoke (/Users/appfoundry/Projects/Unit Testing/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Server.start (/Users/appfoundry/Projects/Unit Testing/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:101:18)
    at Object.exports.run (/Users/appfoundry/Projects/Unit Testing/node_modules/karma/lib/cli.js:231:26)
    at requireCliAndRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma:44:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma:54:12
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:44:21
    at ondir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:187:31)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:153:39
```

I've tried to install the core globally:

```
npm install -g jasmine-core
```

but that didn't solve it.

When I try installing `npm install karma-jasmine` I get an error saying:

```
 karma-jasmine@0.3.6 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine

> Note: Since karma-jasmine 0.3.0 the jasmine library is no longer bundled with karma-jasmine and you have to install it on your own. You can simply do it by:
>
> `npm install jasmine-core --save-dev`

```
$ npm install jasmine-core --save-dev
$ npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
```

Comment: That exactly did it! Thanks. Is it normal though that I don't see `karma-jasmine` or `karma-chrome` folder in my `node-modules` folder? I do see the `jasmine-core`folder now and `karma start karma.conf.js`works

Comment: It depends on how ```npm``` resolves dependencies, but it can be normal, yes. ```npm``` [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/help)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Karma is running globally.

My solution (the easiest and painless at least for me) was to wrap `karma start` command with npm scripts `test` command, so that any command is run in a local context.

In **package.json**, add `"test": "karma start"` in `"scripts": {}`.

`"scripts": {
    "test": "karma start",
    [...]
},`